# Where can I find the top x tags on StackOverflow

Tags: support, badges

Today, while reading [Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) page, I noticed (again) the description for `Generalist`:

> Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags

But, I just can't imagine what the top 40 tags are... how can I find that piece of information?

I also suggest to add a link to *top 40 tags* in that description.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular

Comment: @Robert Can you post this as an answer to let me accept it?

Comment: @Robert BTW, I had no idea Top X means "x most popular", should I suggest this as a re-wording for the badge or it is clear to everyone except me just because I'm not English speaker?

Comment: No, top 40 really means the most popular 40. In America we have something called the "top 40." It's the 40 most popular songs ranked by airplay, sales, etc.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=popular

Gives you the top 80 tags or so, so you can just eyeball the first half of them.

Answer (score 7):

There's actually a [query on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/166672/generalist-progression-see-all-top-40-tags) that you can use to see how far you have to go in each of the top 40 tags to get the Generalist badge.

Comment: just **awesome**, I'll dig into queries to improve my understanding about other badges. :)

Comment: Page not found, it seems it's been removed

Comment: Answer edited to update [the link](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/166672/generalist-progression-see-all-top-40-tags)